# click image list form mysql show div and hide other all image

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, hide, show

I have an issue you would like to ask for help.

I have an issue you would like to ask for help.

I have an image list from mysql (img1, img2, ... imgn) I want to click on each image, it will show a corresponding div img, all others will hide the div tag .

Table 1:
   id
   title
   active
   icon

data: 
   1   Paypal    1     pp.png

Table 2:
   id
   username
   account
   type
   status

Data: 
   1   admin    paypal@mail.com    1   1

Img The number of pages in the record of table 2.
The contents of the div tag from table 2 on

```
$sql=$Db1->query("SELECT * FROM withdraw_options WHERE active='1' ORDER BY id ASC");

            while($temp=$Db1->fetch_array($sql)) {

                $sqlacc = $Db1->query("SELECT * FROM payout_accounts WHERE username='$username' AND type='$temp[id]' ORDER BY id ASC");

                if($Db1->num_rows() != 0) {
                    $reacc = $Db1->fetch_array($sqlacc);
                    $reacc_id = $reacc[id];
                    $reacc_user = $reacc[username];


                    //Filter and remove temp[id]
                    $rvdiv = $Db1->query("SELECT * FROM payout_accounts WHERE username='$username' AND id NOT IN ('$reacc_id')");
                    while ($rem=$Db1->fetch_array($rvdiv)) {

                        $remid = $rem['id'];

                    }


                    $wdo1.="
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                            window.showdiv$reacc[id] = function(fwd$reacc[id]) { 
                                var disp$remid = document.getElementById(fwd$remid); 
                                var disp$reacc[id] = document.getElementById(fwd$reacc[id]);  

                                if(disp$reacc[id].style.display == \"none\") {  
                                    disp$reacc[id].style.display = \"\";
                                    disp$remid.style.display = \"none\"; 
                                }
                            };
                        </script>

                    <div style='float:left;'><a onclick=\"showdiv$reacc[id]('fwd$reacc[id]'); return false;\" href='#'><img width=105 height=64 src=\"images/payments/".$temp[icon]."\" border=\"0\" title=\"We accept payment through ".$temp['title']."!\"></a></div>
                    ";
                    $wdo2.="
                    <form action=\"index.php?view=account&ac=profile&action=withdraw&".$url_variables."\" method=\"post\" name=\"form\" onSubmit=\"return dosub(this)\">
                        <div style=\"display: none;\" id=\"fwd".$reacc[id]."\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"accounttype\" value=\"$temp[id]\">
                        <table width=\"100%\" class=\"tableStyle withdraw\">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Payment address / account #:</th>
                                <td><input readonly type=\"text\" name=\"account\" value='$reacc[account]'> 
                                <a href=\"index.php?view=paymentupdate&".$url_variables."\">$pa_status</a></td>
                            <tr>    
                            <tr>
                                <th>Gross Withdraw: </th>
                                <td>$settings[currency]<input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" size=4  value=\"".(floor($thismemberinfo[balance]*100)/100)."\" onkeyup='calculate()' onchange='calculate2()'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Fee: </th>
                                <td>
                                    <span id=\"feeOut\"></span> or <span id=\"feeminOut\"></span> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Net Withdraw: </th>
                                <td>$settings[currency]<input type=\"text\" name=\"net\" size=4 onkeyup='calculate()'></td>
                            </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Personal Pin:</th>
                                <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"personal_pin\"></td>
                            </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td colspan=2 align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Request\"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        <div style=\"display: none;\" id=\"warn\">
                            <b style=\"color: red\">You do not have enough earnings to request with this payment method!</b>
                        </div>
                    </form>";


                }
            }
```

Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.showdiv$reacc[id] = function(fwd$reacc[id]) { 
var disp$remid = document.getElementById(fwd$remid); 
var disp$reacc[id] = document.getElementById(fwd$reacc[id]);  

if(disp$reacc[id].style.display == \"none\") {  
disp$reacc[id].style.display = \"\";
disp$remid.style.display = \"none\"; 
}
};
</script>
```

html:

```
<center>
                $wdo1
                $wdo2
            </center>";
```

this code it when i click on img1 it show form 1 when i click on img2 it show form 2 but form not hide. i want form 1 hide

thanks

Comment: You misspelled $_SESION[username]

Comment: thanks! i want when click on img 1 then img2, imgn hide and click img2 show then img1 and img n hide